# DJango annotate count filter по ManyToManyField

Tags: django, python-3.8

Есть модель тегов вопросов

```
class QuestionTag(models.Model):
    objects = QuestionTagManager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, primary_key=True)
    ...
```

и модель вопроса

```
class Question(models.Model):
    objects = QuestionManager()
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionTag)
    ...
```

Мне необходимо в менеджере модели тега написать команду вычисления 10 лучших тегов, то есть, отсортировать их по количеству вопросов (по убыванию), связанных с соответствующим тегом полем ManyToManyField, и взять первые 10 элементов от полученного QuerySet. Вот, что у меня получилось

```
class QuestionTagManager(models.Manager):
    def get_top(self):
        return self.annotate(rating=Count(Question, filter=Q(question__tags__contains))).order_by('rating')[:10]
```

Данный запрос очевидно написан неверно и не работает. Подскажите, как правильно написать такой запрос.

---

Вариант с кэшированием поля `count` в модели тега вопроса для подсчёта количества вопросов, в которых указан соответствующий тег, не подходит. 
Нужен именно запрос без использования кешированных полей, поскольку он будет выполняться очень редко (management командой).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

После повторного чтения документации и долгих размышлений я выяснил, что мой запрос был составлен верно, нужно было только убрать `filter`:

```
return self.annotate(rating=Count(Question)).order_by('rating')[:10]
```

DJango автоматически понимает, что считать нужно только те вопросы, которые связаны с тегом полем ManyToManyField, что поначалу было не совсем очевидно.